# How can I calculate whether an entry is before or after a specific date?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, date

I'm using Xcode and I want to compare whether a user-entered date is before or after a specific date.

For example, the user enters "February 12, 1992" into their phone.  I need to determine if that is before or after June 10, 1994.  Then I will take specific action based on this result.

Comment: Can you convert string like "February 12, 1992" to NSDate?

Answer (score 1):

*NSDate* has two methods ***earlierDate:*** and ***laterDate:*** You can also use ***compare:*** method to compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

- Make an NSDate for June 10, 1994
- Make an NSDateFormatter to parse the user input.
- dateFromString: of the date formatter will give you an NSDate
- compare the dates as suggested in the answer by EmptyStack